# How to do aes-ccm encryption in Swift 3

Tags: swift, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt and decrypt in Swift 3 by using AES-CCM.
I have installed module CryptoSwift, and my app is ok to do normal AES128 like this:

```
//aes
let input: Array<UInt8> = [0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e,0x0f]

let key: Array<UInt8> = [0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e,0x0f]
let iv: Array<UInt8> = AES.randomIV(AES.blockSize)

do {
    let encrypted = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: .pkcs7).encrypt(input)
    print(encrypted)
    let decrypted = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: .pkcs7).decrypt(encrypted)
    print(decrypted)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But I cannot find a way to do CCM mode which there is no IV but a nonce shorter than 16 bytes.

Is CryptoSwift able to do AES-CCM or do I have to look for other modules?
Please give me some suggestion.